# Ignite running in Docker (is: General Java-Docker issue)

Tags: java, docker, ignite

I am trying to run ignite in a Docker container (Mac OS X, Docker 1.9.1) as committed in git:

```
# Start from a Java image.
FROM java:7

# Ignite version
ENV IGNITE_VERSION 1.5.0-b1

WORKDIR /opt/ignite

ADD http://www.us.apache.org/dist/ignite/1.5.0-b1/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin.zip /opt/ignite/ignite.zip

# Ignite home
ENV IGNITE_HOME /opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin

RUN unzip ignite.zip

RUN rm ignite.zip

# Copy sh files and set permission
ADD ./run.sh $IGNITE_HOME/

RUN chmod +x $IGNITE_HOME/run.sh

CMD $IGNITE_HOME/run.sh
```

After building it locally to `apache/ignite` and running the image with following command, the container 'hangs'

```
docker run --expose=4700-4800 -it -p 47500-47600:47500-47600 -p 47100-47200:47100-47200 --net=host -e "CONFIG_URI=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/examples/config/example-default.xml" apacheignite/ignite-docker
```

When connecting to the container (`docker exec -ti apache/ignite /bin/bash`) and running the command in verbose mode via bash, it hangs on `org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineRandomNumberGenerator`:

```
bash -x /opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/bin/ignite.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/examples/config/example-default.xml
```

Output where it hangs:

```
+ CP='/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/ignite-spring/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/licenses/*'
++ /usr/bin/java -cp '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/ignite-spring/*:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0-b1-bin/libs/licenses/*' org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineRandomNumberGenerator
```

Looking at the code of `CommandLineRandomNumberGenerator`, I don't see anything special, just one line to generate a UUID. Are there other things that are automatically started somehow that causes locking a threat so that the application cannot exit?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the logs? Can you provide them for investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a docker issue with java in general, see also:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180

Several solutions possible:

- create a docker machine as follows and run it in here (cfr. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180#issuecomment-162568282):

  docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-storage-driver overlay overlaymachine
- Add System.exit(0) explicit at the end of each main method (cfr. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180#issuecomment-161129296)
- Wait for next docker patched version (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180#issuecomment-170656525)

I think it would be good practice (for now) to add System.exit to all main methods in Ignite since this is independent of alternative hacks on docker or linux in general (linux kernel need AUFS upgrade and many machine may lag behind before that). This way future Ignite version can safely be installed on older kernels also.

Comment: In my understanding Ignite community can add System.exit to the classes that used by startup scripts in order to support current and previous Docker versions. I've created a ticket that you can track or assign on yourself contributing to Ignite: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2377

Presently you can create your own version of CommandLineRandomNumberGenerator adding System.exit to the end of main function.